# How can we prove $\lim_{n\to +\infty} \sin(\sqrt{n^2+1}\pi)$ exists, in another way?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-explanation

I was reading about this question just now [Evaluating $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sin(\sqrt{n^2+1}\pi)$. (WolframAlpha says it doesn't exist; I get $0$.)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4613721/evaluating-lim-n-to-infty-sin-sqrtn21-pi-wolframalpha-says-it-doe) and I immediately got intrigued for I would have never came up with such a trick to evaluate the limit.

So I thought about: how could we prove that limit exists, without using such a trick?

For example, I studied about the Heine method, for limits with successions. This for example rapidly can prove the limit $\lim_{n\to +\infty} \sin(n)$ does not exist. Indeed I can choose a sequence $a_n = \pi n$ such that $a_n \to +\infty$ as $n\to +\infty$ or another sequence $b_n = \frac{2n+1}{2} \pi$, and if the limits exists then it does not depend upon the chosen sequence. In this case, I would get $\sin(a_n) = 0$ whereas $\sin(b_n) = \pm 1$, so the limit does not exist.

Can we use a similar argument to prove the existence of the other limit (the one in the linked question)?

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \sin(\sqrt{n^2+1}\pi)$$

Thank you so much.

Comment: Which other limit?

Comment: @Numb3rs  there is no need to be rude.  I didn't understand your question either.  How could you use a method designed to prove non-existence to show that a particular limit does, in fact, exist?  It's not much use to find a whole lot of subsequences which converge to the same thing, after all...that might be suggestive but unless you can show more, it probably won't lead to a proof.

Comment: The limit does not exist. Please do not be rude with people who are giving up their time to help you.

Comment: $\sqrt{n^2+1}$ is irrational. Thus $\pi \sqrt{n^2+1}$ is never an integer multiple of $\pi.$ Therefore $\sin\left(\pi\sqrt{n^2+1}\right)\neq 0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}.$ The function values actually jump around and cannot converge.

Comment: @lulu I wrote down a proof for a limit that does not exist, unsing the Heine method for limits. What I am asking is, since that method can be used wither to prove also that certain limits exist, if we could use it, or another way instad of what the other guy did

Comment: @copper.hat I apologise if I was rude. In the other answer though, they say it exists...

Comment: @Numb3rs My turn to apologise. I forgot to account for $n$ being natural.

Comment: @copper.hat What about Marius SL comment? Well I'm getting confused o.O

Comment: @MariusS.L. It certainly approaches $0$, because $\pi \sqrt{n^2+1}$ gets indefinitely closer to $n\pi$.

Comment: @Numb3rs You need to look at $\sqrt{n^2+1} \pmod 1$ because of the nature of $\sin$.

Comment: @copper.hat So it suffices to say that as $n\to +\infty$, with $n\in\mathbb{N}$,  $\sqrt{n^2+1}\pi$ goes like $n\pi$ and then the sine is zero? (Which I couldn't do if $n \in \mathbb{R}$)

Comment: @Numb3rs it reduces to showing $\lim_n (\sqrt{n^2+1}-n)=0$.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, with using the method the other guy used. But assuming we do not use that...

Comment: @Vishu But it is $n\pi + \text{sth.}$ and this something doesn't ever vanish.

Comment: @MariusS.L. This something gets smaller and smaller

Comment: @Vishu Oops! I (mistakenly) thought it started right at the first digit.

Comment: Numb3rs Your method to prove that $\lim_{n\to +\infty} \sin(n)$ does not exist is flawed because your $a_n$'s and $b_n$'s are not integers.

Comment: @AnneBauval Sorry that was my mistake: for that limit I meant $n$ as a real number!

Comment: You can also take a look at this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4458695/1061348

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$ \sqrt{n^2+1}=n\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}=n\left(1+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)=n+o(1) $$
therefore $\sin(\pi\sqrt{n^2+1})=\sin(n\pi+o(1))$. If you mean that $n$ takes integer values, then the limit exists and is $0$. If you want $n$ to be real (as mentioned in the comments) then the limit does not exist, taking $a_n=n$ and $b_n=2n+1/2$ gives you two different limits, namely $0$ and $1$ respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $n$ is an integer and using $b_n=\sqrt{n^2+1}-n$

$$a_n= \sin \left(\pi  \sqrt{n^2+1}\right)=\sin (n\pi +b_n\pi )=\color{red}{(-1)^n}\,\sin(b_n\pi)+\cos(b_n\pi)$$

Now, by Taylor
$$b_n=\sqrt{n^2+1}-n=\frac{1}{2 n}-\frac{1}{8
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$

$$\sin(b_n\pi)=\frac{\pi }{2 n}-\frac{\pi  \left(6+\pi ^2\right)}{48
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$
$$\cos(b_n\pi)=1-\frac{\pi ^2}{8 n^2}+\frac{\pi ^2 \left(24+\pi ^2\right)}{384
   n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^6}\right)$$

So,
$$a_{2n}=\frac{\pi }{4 n}-\frac{\pi  \left(6+\pi ^2\right)}{384
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)\quad \to ~0^+$$
$$a_{2n+1}=-\frac{\pi }{4 n}+\frac{\pi }{8 n^2}+\frac{\pi  \left(\pi
   ^2-18\right)}{384 n^3}-\frac{\pi  \left(\pi ^2-2\right)}{256
   n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)\quad \to ~0^-$$